# Two Dataframes with same columns (Update existing ones and append new ones ,keep old ones in third dataframe)

Tags: sql, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, join

I have Two Dataframes consider New DF, Existing DF the columns in both DFs are same
Consider primary key as Customer Key
I want to create a third dataframe which will
combine both dfs,
if a matching customer key is found update details from new to existing
keep the other records of existing and new as it is.

I tried a full outer join on customer key and also checking to see if new df column value is not null then use that else use existing.
How do I do the above in spark scala code.

Spark SQL->

```html
SELECT CASE
         WHEN deltacustkeytabl.create_time_stamp IS NOT NULL THEN
         deltacustkeytabl.create_time_stamp
         ELSE existinghdfstabl.create_time_stamp
       END AS CREATE_TIME_STAMP,
       CASE
         WHEN deltacustkeytabl.customer_key IS NOT NULL THEN
         deltacustkeytabl.customer_key
         ELSE existinghdfstabl.customer_key
       END AS CUSTOMER_KEY,
       CASE
         WHEN deltacustkeytabl.chainid IS NOT NULL THEN deltacustkeytabl.chainid
         ELSE existinghdfstabl.chainid
       END AS CHAINID
FROM   existinghdfstabl
       FULL OUTER JOIN deltacustkeytabl
                    ON existinghdfstabl.customer_key =deltacustkeytabl.customer_key
```

*there are 40 + columns to match from

Answer (score 0):

So basically your requirement is:

Old DF

```
+--------+
|pk | val|
|--------|
|1  | v1 |
|2  | v1 |
+--------+
```

New DF:

```
+--------+
|pk | val|
|--------|
|2  | v2 |
|3  | v1 |
+--------+
```

Third DF:

```
+--------+
|pk | val|
|--------|
|1  | v1 |
|2  | v2 |
|3  | v1 |
+--------+
```

In that case:

```
select * from old_df where pk not in (select pk from new_df)
union
select * from new_df
```

Comment: thanks will try the above , also there is a create_time_stamp column if there is a customer key in the the existing df and it also comes in new df it should be pushed into the third dataframe with the create time stamp of existing record but other details of new